# Java bitwise right shift of 255 into byte value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a short counter which increments and is used as an identifier.  I need to send the identifier as binary data on a network socket.

So if I have a short value I can do this to 'pack' in two bytes:

```
short id = 1;
byte val = (byte)(id & 0xFF);
byte val2 = (byte)((id >>> 8) & 0xFF);
System.out.printf("id=%d, val = id & 0xFF = %d, val2 = (id >>> 8) & 0xFF = %d\n", 
                   id, val, val2);
```

Now when id = 1 this works fine.

But when id = 255 I get:

```
short id = 255;
byte val = (byte)(id & 0xFF);           //val = -1
byte val2 = (byte)((id >>> 8) & 0xFF);  //val2 = 0
```

Now I know that 255 in binary is 11111111 and this means -1 for a java byte value.  Am I correct in thinking that how java interprets it is immaterial and if I send as byte binary 11111111 then at the other end it can interpret this however it wants?

Comment: `val2` is not -1, it's 0. You shift all eight bits out of the value, so you end up with zero.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I have edited.

Comment: By the way, it's redundant to do `& 0xFF` and then cast to `byte`. In other words, it's sufficient to write `(byte)(id >>> 8)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thinkings are right.

Just for your information: there is a very nice class that does this for you. It is called [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

```
Socket socket = ...;
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

/* Write a short */
short out = 255;
dos.writeShort(out);

/* Read a short */
short in = dis.readShort();
```

Comment: Ah I only looked at write.  writeShort is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all data types are interpreted as signed. That is, any number with most significant bit equal to 1 is a negative number. When you send the number over the network it doesn't matter how it's interpreted by Java, as you still send the same bits. So yes, your code will work as intended.

Comment: Re: "all data types are interpreted as signed": Except for `char`, which is an unsigned 16-bit value. :-)